# How to find out why DbccFilesCompact is suspended?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a DB, which i'm shrinking now

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (MYDB, 5); GO
```

This process lasts already **1:00:23:43**

Yesterday i've launched a script to check the status of shrinking:

```
SELECT percent_complete, start_time, status, command, estimated_completion_time, cpu_time, total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
```

And its result does not change from yesterday not for a half of percent. So, it means, the shrinking process is totally freezed.
How can i check what exactly suspends shrinking?

**UPD:**

`EXEC sp_who2` returns such results:

Shrinking is blocked by another one prosees, with ID 70:
[image]

Here is info from sp_who2 for this process:
[image]

And here is info for this these two processes from Activiry Monitor:

It says SHRINKDATABASE is wayting for some page (??):
[image]

And here is info for process with ID 70:
[image]

So, what is going on, and what is that AWAINTING COMMAND, which blocks shrinking?

Comment: can you run `sp_whoisactive` exec requests wont show inactive queries

Comment: http://whoisactive.com/downloads/

Comment: also check out this link ,specifically troubleshooting section.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkdatabase-transact-sql... and see if you are running those kind of operations

Comment: TheGameiswar, thanks for your comments. I've launched sp_who2, as can't use sp_whoisactive right now, and found some extra info, but can't get whats going on still.

Comment: Thank you for posting this and the updates! They were really helpful